# programmatically enable and disable theme from update hook

Tags: 8, updating

I need to programmatically update my default theme and disable bartik on a live site. I know I need to update the config. In Drupal 7 I would have used `theme_enable()`, but I am not sure how to do this in Drupal 8. 
Below my function sets 'mycustomtheme' by default but it does not enable the theme. Thanks in advance.

```
  function mysite_deploy_update_8001() {
      \Drupal::configFactory()
      ->getEditable('system.theme')
      ->set('default', 'mycustomtheme')
      ->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the theme installer service to enable and disable themes .

Install a list of themes:

```
\Drupal::service('theme_installer')->install(['mytheme']);
```

Uninstall a list of themes:

```
\Drupal::service('theme_installer')->uninstall(['mytheme']);
```

Reference: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ThemeInstaller.php/function/ThemeInstaller%3A%3Ainstall/8.2.x